# How to get toString method for the Nullable Enum for building an Expression Call

Tags: c#, reflection, expression-trees

```
enum StrategyType
{
   Straddle,
   Butterfly
}

class Test
{
   public StrategyType strategy {get; set;}
}

bool IsNullableEnum(Type t)
{
  Type u = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(t);
  return (u != null) && u.IsEnum;
}

var toStringMethod = typeof(Enum).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { });

var entity = new Test();
var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(entity);
Expression memberProperty = Expression.Property(entityParameter, "strategy");

    memberProperty = Expression.Call(memberProperty, toStringMethod);
```

If I change the StrategyType Enum in the Test class to Nullable like below:

```
StrategyType? strategyType {get; set;}
```

Then, I am unable to find out the way to get the toString method for Nullable Enum, similar to the one I have done for simple Enum StrategyType.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: This code has several syntax errors, making it hard to help you, e.g. where is `prop` declared?

Comment: I have corrected it.

Comment: I meant `Expression.Parameter(entity)`, I think this should be `Expression.Parameter(entity.GetType())` or something similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you should emit call to the *actual* type method, not `Enum`. It would work for both nullable and non nullable value types, including `enum`s.

You can do that by using the actual type in `GetMethod` call, or (preferable) the `Expressing.Call` overload with `string methodName`, e.g.

```cs
// (Test e) =>
var entityParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Test), "e");
// e.strategy
Expression source = Expression.Property(entityParameter, "strategy");
// e.strategy.ToString()
var toStringCall = Expression.Call(source, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Nullable<>` is a little tricky. When you find such a property you have to check against the given entity what you get back from `prop.GetValue(entity)`. Either this is `null` (and trying to call `ToString()` would be impossible) or you get back the value type (but boxed as an object), but you can call the *normal* `ToString()` method.

```
if (IsNullableEnum(prop.PropertyType) && prop.GetValue(entity) != null)
    memberProperty = Expression.Call(memberProperty, toStringMethod);
```

Comment: interesting that calling `ToString()` on `Nullable<>` without value (`null`) is possible without reflection (it always returns an empty string)

Comment: This does not work: "Method 'System.String ToString()' declared on type 'System.Enum' cannot be called with instance of type 'System.Nullable`1[StrategyType]'"

Comment: And if I change toString method to this: `var toStringMethod = typeof(Nullable<>).GetMethod("ToString", new Type[] { });` then I get this error: Method System.String ToString() contains generic parameters (Parameter 'method')

Comment: Could you post a complete code example that throws your current error?

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve it myself same day and I forgot to revisit the question here. Thank you for your time.